# NetBeans 8.2 Ubuntu c++ Code Assistance doesn't work

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans, netbeans-8, code-assist

I installed ubuntu and g++ on my Ubuntu PC. It compiles and builds code, but Code Assistance always says `No suggestions`. And it's very sad. I checked directories in Code Assistance preferences. It looks like ok.
[image]

What should I check more to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you started your project inside Netbeans? Or are you trying to import a project to Netbeans?

Comment: Yes, I created new project in NetBeans

Comment: I always go to Eclipse with C++ in Ubuntu. I'm not sure what is going wrong then as in your picture it seems that Netbeans should have enough information for code assistance.

Comment: :) Eclipse might be the answer. Thanks